# Convert date format to mm-dd-yyyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, foreach

I am populating a list "results" with dates. In a query result I am getting a set of values .. where date value is in this format ..

> 20120510000000000

In my code, I am doing the following..

```
    query = service.GetData();
    List<String> results = new List<String>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        results.Add(item.InDate);  
        //This is in this format - 20120510000000000
        //Here I want to convert to mm-dd-yyyy                              
    }
    return results;
```

I would like to convert the above date format into "mm/dd/yyyy" and post it to "results" list.

Comment: What format is 20120510000000000?

Comment: Is the original format yyyymmdd000000000?

Comment: Is your data is in format `YYYYMMddhhmmss000`

Comment: yes thats the format I am getting from the database..

Comment: i remember back in the day, before we had stackoverflow, we had this thing called API documentation, but we dont need that anymore

Comment: @mkoryak I have a feeling we're going to have a generation of failed programmers. Nothing new or groundbreaking will be written for another 20 years after the current generation of gurus retires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date is guaranteed to be in the [year][month][day][hour][minute][second][millisecond] format (looks like it), you can use a simple string manipulation:

```
var newDate = item.InDate.Substring(2, 2) + "-" +
              item.InDate.Substring(4, 2) + "-" +
              item.InDate.Substring(0, 4);
```

if you want it in a DateTime object, you can use the DateTime.ParseExact method:

```
var newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(indate, "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: using your second solution...at the line results.Add(newDate), it gives error - Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments –

Comment: I got it to work with..  results.Add(newDate.Date.ToShortDateString());

Answer (score 3):

```
query = service.GetData();
    List<String> results = new List<String>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        var unformattedDate = item.InDate;
        var formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(unformattedDate,
                                    "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff",
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        results.Add(formattedDate);                              
    }
    return results;
```

Comment: This does not parse the value correctly, you need to specify the remaining arguments: `yyyyMMddHHmmssfff`

Comment: at the line results.Add(formattedDate), it gives error - Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: you'll want to say `results.Add(formattedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))`

Comment: yes..I got it to work with..  results.Add(formattedDate.Date.ToShortDateString()); probably the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided above are correct. Better store the format of the date your expecting and the date format you are converting to display, store it in the config file or resource file. Its not good to hardcode.